# Choosing 3G or EDGE on Mobile Broadband

Tags: modem, 3g, huawei, broadband

I'm using Mobile Broadband with the modem HUAWEI K3765 . 
I have installed the driver from here : http://www.betavine.net/bvportal/resources/datacards/devices .

In the modem's official management application (supporting only Windows OS, not Linux) there is an option for using either an EDGE or 3G connection, depending on the signal strength.

Using this option, the modem defaults to 3G. Only when the signal is low, it automatically connects via EDGE. You can suppress this behavior by choosing the option "Connect via 3G only".

Now I'm using Ubuntu 11.04. As I said I couldn't install the official application, I just installed the mentioned driver. This modem automatically connects via EDGE when 3G signal is low. I want to connect via 3G **always**, also when the 3G Signal is low.

So what I should do?

Comment: Guide over here http://biggenius.org/modem-manager-gui-for-ubuntu/

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](https://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/developers/api/08/settings-spec-08.html) it is possible to force 3G with the parameter `network-type`:

Following Options are available for the parameter `network-type`

- `-1` any connection (Default value)
- `0` for Only 3G
- `1` for GPRS/EDGE only
- `2` prefer 3G
- `3` prefer 2G

These changes have to made in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/your_3g_connection`. Put `network-type 0` in the section `[gsm]`

Option `0` is what you requested, *but* I would recommend using `2`. If your signal is too weak for 3G, you'll have *no connection at all* with the setting `0`. Whereas the option `2` will go down to EDGE/GPRS in that case. Better 2G than nothing at all, isn't it?

**Graphical Way**

You can achieve the same result with the "Network-Connections" dialogue. [Look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56039/how-can-i-force-a-usb-modem-to-only-connect-via-edge-and-not-3g) for a comprehensive, step-by-step guide.

Comment: There is nothing in the documentation page you've referred. Can you update the link

Answer (score 2):

When you connect using ubuntu network manager aplet i think it's automaticaly switch form 3G to Edge eventhough network will be disconnected for a while.

if you want such us standalone network manager like *sierra wireless watcher* or *huawei mobile partner* you can use application named **UMTSMON**, you can monitor the signal, choose the network type, even send sms from this application *(if supported)*

you can download the source here :

- http://umtsmon.sourceforge.net/downloads.shtml

*here is the screenshoot :*

[image]

Comment: There isn't my card (HUAWEI K3765) on supported cards list .

Answer (score 1):

Some problems are solved better outside of the software, and I believe this might be one.  Ive worked in the wireless sector for years, and in my mind the easiest way would be to use the backdoor in the device... for example if this is a android device its http://rwireless.blogspot.com/2009/03/hidden-menus-in-android-phone.html <--documented here..  You can usually then tell the device to choose a specific network, and to only use that network.  Without knowing the specifics of the device its hard to say what your code is, but almost all devices have one..

Comment: It's a HUAWEI K3765 . Which informations do you need?