# How can I force a USB modem to only connect via EDGE and not 3G?

Tags: 11.04, network-manager, 3g, usb-modem

How do I get Network-admin to restrict connection to GSM (Edge) instead of flipping between 3G and Edge and lose connection. Usually it works out-of-the box, but at my current location there are a lot of radio shadows, so the recommendation from my ISP is that I should lock to Edge - which can be done using their own driver in Windows.

How can I do this in Ubuntu

Ubuntu 11.04
Modem: Huawei E220
ISP: Telia mobilt bredband kontant

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

click on network applet > `Edit connections..` > Mobile Broadband

select your mobile broadband connection and click `Edit`

[image]

you will see dialog box as below,

[image]

change `Type:` to `2G (GPRS/EDGE)`

[image]

click `Save`. now whenever you try to connect to internet it'll use only `EDGE` even if `3G` network is available.

Comment: It doesn't work on 15.10: when I open the settings again it don't show me that it uses 2g.